# Attribute with XML namespace

Tags: xml, go

The following struct is used to marshall SAML XML elements such as `OrganizationName`, `OrganizationDisplayName` & `OrganizationURL`.

```
type LocalizedName struct {
    Lang  string `xml:"xml lang,attr"`
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

The `Lang` attribute is within the `xml` namespace. The generated XML from the encoding/xml package includes relative namespaces:

```
<Organization>
  <OrganizationName xmlns:_xml="xml" _xml:lang="en">name</OrganizationName>
  <OrganizationDisplayName xmlns:_xml="xml" _xml:lang="en">name</OrganizationDisplayName>
  <OrganizationURL xmlns:_xml="xml" _xml:lang="en">http://www.example.com/</OrganizationURL>
</Organization>
```

I was expecting the elements to not use relative namespaces as they seem to be considered to be insecure, [although I do not understand why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769529/xml-why-are-relative-namespaces-bad):

```
<OrganizationName xml:lang="en">name</OrganizationName>
```

What causes the relative namespaces to be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to generate something like this:

```
<OrganizationName xml:lang="en">name</OrganizationName>
```

you can use the following:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

//OrganizationName Name
type OrganizationName struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"OrganizationName"`
    Lang    string   `xml:"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace lang,attr,omitempty"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

//Organization Organization Entity
type Organization struct {
    XMLName          xml.Name         `xml:"Organization"`
    OrganizationName OrganizationName `xml:"OrganizationName"`
}

func main() {
    v := Organization{
        OrganizationName: OrganizationName{
            Lang:  "en",
            Value: "Hisham Karam",
        },
    }
    output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(v, "  ", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n%s", string(output))

}
```

output:

```
  <Organization>
      <OrganizationName xml:lang="en">Hisham Karam</OrganizationName>
  </Organization>
```

go version:

```
go version go1.10.3 darwin/amd64
```